# Как реализовать автоподсказку при заполнении?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Хочу реализовать автоподсказку при заполнении `richtextbox` (также, подсказка должна двигаться по поставленному курсору на дорожке текста).

**Пример:**

Ввод: `"i"`

Вывод:

```
"int"  
"int16"  
"int32"  
"int64"  
и т.д
```

---

[image: Как в Visual Studio]

Как сделать такое?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365974/Autocomplete-Menu

Comment: А что то встроенное по мимо всяких библеотек?

Comment: насколько мне известно, нет

Comment: [FastColoredTextBox](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox) и [Autocomplete Menu](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365974/Autocomplete-Menu) использовать в паре

Comment: Если ни в какую не хотите использовать сторонние библиотеки, можете подсмотреть идеи реализации кода здесь: [Пишем автодополнение для ваших CLI проектов](https://habr.com/ru/post/515946/)

Comment: richTextBox1.SelectionStart отображает позицию курсора от начала а мне нужно координаты его, как получить координаты?

Comment: Не спрашивайте в комментариях. Отредактируйте вопрос. А лучше - создайте новую тему.